# mail function not working in OO PHP

Tags: php, oop

I tried the following:

a.php

```
<?php
    class Page
    {
        function go(){
            echo "1";
            send();
        }

        function send(){
            mail("whatever@gmail.com","subj","hi");
        }
    }
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php 
require("a.php");
$page=new Page();
$page->go();
?>
```

b.php doesn't neither sends a mail nor t echo anything. When I put echo before send in the function go(), PHP echo "1" but doesn't send anything. I thought maybe there's something wrong with the mail() function so I changed b.php to:

```
<?php 
require("a.php");
$page=new Page();
$page->send();
?>
```

and everything works fine. What is the problem with the initial code?

Comment: You need to configure STMP server in your PHP settings.

Comment: @Pupil The mail function works fine when I call it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a mail function. You are trying to call a function that isn't labeled correctly. In this type you're attempting to call a static function. But the function you're calling is not labeled static. You can fix this a few different ways however.

Your echo doesn't work because it can't find the function you're referencing in `go()`.

```
// best use
class Page{
    public function go(){
        echo "yay";
        $this->send();
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```
// static isn't recommended most often, but this will work.
class Page{
    // same go function
    public static function send(){
       // same
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How did I miss that?!

Comment: Super super common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Been awhile since I've used PHP, but you have to use $this to call the send method from a class method.  See below:

```
<?php
    class Page
    {
        function go(){
            echo "1";
            $this->send();  # Added the $this-> to the function call
        }

        function send(){
            mail("whatever@gmail.com","subj","hi");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `send();`

to

```
$this->send();
```

`send()` is a class method not a function, hence it cannot be called without `$this` in this case.